# How can I register a Google AdWords conversion in very backend PHP?

Tags: php, google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

Basically, as part of our system, a conversion is only registered when someone offline decides to go ahead and offer the service. This then triggers a load of backend PHP to run, etc. The customer is not shown any kind of landing page or anything front end that indicates the service is complete and the purchase has happened.

I'm aware that Google AdWords has a tracking tag that you place on any page that fires off and marks a conversion when that page is visited, but like I said, we don't have any such page.

Can anyone suggest anyway that I can achieve conversion tracking without any front end, using primarily backend PHP?

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case for the [offline conversions upload feature](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2998031?hl=en) of AdWords.

The only prerequisite is that you record the `gclid` parameter of every visitor that actually converts on your site (of course, this requires you to activate auto-tagging in your Adwords account).

Once you have that information, you can upload your conversions as CSV file into your AdWords account.

If you'd rather want to submit the offline conversions in an automated fashion, have a look at the corresponding [example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201702/Remarketing/UploadOfflineConversions.php) of the official PHP Adwords API client library for an idea how this is done.